# Single board computer GPRS and GPS

Tags: linux-kernel, gps, embedded-linux, gprs

I am running a project on `cubieboard` and it is fine enough. But current project require a same configuration with embedded GPRS(with sim card holder) and GSM module. If I implement it with USB 3G dongle and GPS device the cost is not acceptable. I want a embedded solution which can save cost.

#### Can any one tell me cost effective way to implement GPRS and GPS in cubieboard ?

## or

#### Alternative Single board computer with same feature like 4GB NAND, ARM Processor and Linux Kernel (u-boot) with GPRS & GPS module support ?

Comment: Depending on your I/O requirements, perhaps a previous generation Android phone model known to be not *too* difficult to install a custom build on?

Comment: @ChrisStratton But is there any android motherboard like `cubieboard` with those feature??

Comment: @ChrisStratton can you share some link to get this type of single board computer??

Comment: What is "cost effective"?  There is a $200 combination using Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (relatively) cost-effective way I've came across is this:
[http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/GPS/GPRS/GSM_Module_V3.0_%28SKU:TEL0051%29](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/GPS/GPRS/GSM_Module_V3.0_%28SKU%3aTEL0051%29)

It is arduino compatible, however, I believe that you are experienced enough (or willing to become) to configure it for the cubieboard.